# Double clicking on a Zip file in Finder re-downloads it from web

Tags: macos, zip, finder

I'm experiencing a strange behavior, after downloading any zip file, when I double click it, expecting it would open, instead it reconnects to its website and re-downloads itself.

The file is opened with Archive Utility.

Can I change this behavior? What should I check for?

Comment: Every Zip file or just a particular one? What program opens the Zip file?

Comment: Every Zip file and the app is Archive Utility the default mac one, but it's a new behavior